# TikZ: How to scale the spy box with the tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

With the help of [How do I zoom a rectangle area in pgfplots adding a gray background even for the axis labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102477/how-do-i-zoom-a-rectangle-area-in-pgfplots-adding-a-gray-background-even-for-the) and [No content in zoom Tikz spy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62953/no-content-in-zoom-tikz-spy) I have been able to get the most of what I want. Using stand alone this example looks likes this:

[image: Output]

I have used the following "standalone" code to generate the picture.

```
% Source 1: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102477/
% Source 2: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62953/

\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tikz}% no needs since pgfplots loads already it
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} % Set the pgf plots to a current version
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{new spy style/.style={spy scope={%
 magnification=5,
 size=1.25cm, 
 connect spies,
 every spy on node/.style={
   rectangle,
   draw,
   },
 every spy in node/.style={
   draw,
   rectangle,
   }
  }
 }
} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[new spy style]
\begin{axis}[%
  height=0.3\textwidth,
  width=0.96\textwidth,
  name = BG,
  unbounded coords=jump,
  scale only axis,
  xmin=-3.68158764150225, xmax=4.05456770289782,
  ymin=-1.44575077919192, ymax=1.15200357048622,
  axis lines*=left,
  axis equal image]
  \addplot [
    color=blue,
    solid,
    mark=+,
    mark options={solid},
    ]
    {sin(deg(x))};     
  \addplot [
    color=red,
    solid,
    mark=*,
    mark options={solid},
    ]
    {sin(deg(x))+0.1};     
  \addplot [
    color=green,
    solid,
    mark=x,
    mark options={solid},
    ]
    {sin(deg(x))-0.1};     
    \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:0,0.0); 
    \coordinate (spyviewer) at (axis cs:1.7,-.5); 

\end{axis}
%using axis coordinates and without "spy style" defined above
\spy[width=2cm,height=3cm] on (spypoint) in node [fill=white] at (spyviewer); 

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

As you can see the I have been able to set the coordinates for \spy relative to the axis (near end of code). However I have not been able to define the size in the same way. As a consequence the graph may look different if used within a main document.

I am quite sure that this has to do with my use of "height" and "width" in the axis setup and/or the usage of "cm" in the \spy command.

My preferred solution would be something where I use the "\spy" in a way that I can refer to the coordinate system of the axis to determine its size as well. Any attempt of moving the "\spy" command inside the "axis" have so fare failed me.

---

The motivation behind this question can be seen form the following two images using my real data.

If compiled as standalone:
[image: Standalone]
And for comparison when compiled in the main document:
[image: As part of main document]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the entire image is scaled by `\textwidth` I figured that it would be nice to also use this to scale `\spy` box. So replacing

```
\spy[width=2cm,height=3cm] on (spypoint) in node [fill=white] at (spyviewer);
```

with

```
\spy[width=0.2\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth] on (spypoint) in node [fill=white] at (spyviewer);
```

was all that needed to be done. If the box is now placed and sized correctly in the `standalone` environment its size and position are preserved in the main document as well.